# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, cpanel

While installing a script I am getting this error:

> MySQL error: Could not connect to database. 
>   Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

and I do not know why this is happening. My hosting provider is siteground, using cPanel.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the way you try to connect to your database. We need code to help you with it ;)

Comment: `using password: NO` you aren't sending a password. Just a guess you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection string, you aren't sending a password as your error suggests.

Worth checking that you actually have permission as well.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';
```